# Merge between two elements of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following example array:

```
[[ 3,  5,  6],
 [ 4, -1, -1],
 [ 5,  7, -1],
 [ 1,  6, -1],
 [ 1,  0,  6],
 [ 3,  4,  8],
 [ 2,  3,  5],
 [ 2, -1, -1],
 [ 0,  4,  5],
 [ 0,  5, -1]]
```

I am trying to:

- merge two of the elements into one (in this case elements idx 2 and 4)
- delete duplicates in the merged element (if any)
- move any (-1) to the end of the element
- supplement the rest of the elements with (-1) to pertain the rectangle shape and symmetry of the array
- move merged element to position 0, like in the example below:

  ```
    [[ 5,  7,  1,  0,  6, -1],
     [ 3,  5,  6, -1, -1, -1],
     [ 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
     [ 1,  6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
     [ 3,  4,  8, -1, -1, -1],
     [ 2,  3,  5, -1, -1, -1],
     [ 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
     [ 0,  4,  5, -1, -1, -1],
     [ 0,  5, -1, -1, -1, -1]]
  ```

Please suggest possible solution.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Could you please edit with more details?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why people are saying your question is unclear (it's quite clear IMO), but here is a function that can merge any of the two elements like you specified:

```py
import pprint

def move_n1_to_end(row): #function that moves all -1's to the end
  n1_count = 0
  for i in row:
    if i==-1:
      n1_count += 1
  new_row = [e for e in row if e != -1]
  new_row.extend([-1] * n1_count)
  return new_row

def merge_move(arr, idx1, idx2):
  merged_list = [*dict.fromkeys(arr[idx1] + arr[idx2])] #merge and remove duplicates
  merged_list = move_n1_to_end(merged_list) #move -1's to the end
  #removes the two lists that were merged
  arr = [arr[i] for i in range(len(arr)) if i not in [idx1, idx2]]
  #make a copy of the merged list (essentially moves it to the front of the new matrix)
  new_arr = [merged_list[:]]
  #find the maximum length of all the rows
  max_length = max(len(e) for e in arr + new_arr)
  for i in range(len(arr)): #for each index of the original matrix...
   #set row to the i'th row
   row = arr[i]
   #move all -1's to the end
   row = move_n1_to_end(row)
   #insert -1's at the end of each row to make the matrix rectangular
   new_arr.append(row + [-1] * (max_length-len(row))) 
   #append the result to the new matrix
  return new_arr #return the resulting matrix

test_matrix = [[ 3,  5,  6],
 [ 4, -1, -1],
 [ 5,  7, -1],
 [ 1,  6, -1],
 [ 1,  0,  6],
 [ 3,  4,  8],
 [ 2,  3,  5],
 [ 2, -1, -1],
 [ 0,  4,  5],
 [ 0,  5, -1]]

pprint.pprint(merge_move(test_matrix, 2, 4))

"""
Output:
[[5, 7, 1, 0, 6, -1],
 [3, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1],
 [4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [1, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [3, 4, 8, -1, -1, -1],
 [2, 3, 5, -1, -1, -1],
 [2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [0, 4, 5, -1, -1, -1],
 [0, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1]]
"""
```

Comment: I applied the code you provided but the result was unexpected and not like in your example: f_vars_r = np.array[[2,4,0,-1], [1,3,-1,-1], [ 2,4,0,-1], [0,1,-1,-1], [0,3,2,-1], [2,4,4,-1]]; result: [2,7,-2], [2, 4, 0, -1], [1,3,-1,-1], [0,1,-1,-1], [2,4,4,-1]] It looks like instead of merging the two rows it sums up each of the elements of the rows. Even the sum looks incorrect because if it was correct the first row should look like this: [2, 7, 2, -2] This confuses me and I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Also the resulting array is displayed differently - like a string of 1D arrays (and not in rectangular shape as my other arrays, I and don`t know why. I wonder - is it possible to be because it just an array and not a numpy array?

Comment: @PetarAndreev Oh oops, didn’t realize you were using numpy. This only works with regular 2d arrays.

Comment: Is there a way of how to maybe transform numpy array into regular array, apply the code that you provided and then again transform to numpy so that I can continue working with it? Or if not, how can I overcome the issue?